# Comparing File1 and File2 to comment out matching pattern in File2

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have 2 files which are lists containing test names. One file contains the base test name such as `usb30_tb_7_10` and in the other file it is shown as `'include "usb30_tb_7_10.sv"`. I want to take all names from **list`** which are the base names (without include or .sv) and find them in **list2** and comment out the entire line.

I.e.:

**List 1**

```
test1
test3
```

**List 2 Before Comment**

```
'include "test1.sv"
'include "test2.sv"
'include "test3.sv"
'include "test4.sv"
```

**List 2 After compare**

```
//'include "test1.sv"
'include "test2.sv"
//'include "test3.sv"
'include "test4.sv"
```

Im still new to grep/sed/awk, but I havent been able to find a solution to this yet.

I've seen answers involving awk which takes a specific pattern as the input, but that doesnt help me too much.

I tried to do the following:

```
awk '-include list1.lst {print "// " $0; next} 1' list2.sv
```

But it didnt work (or even accept the command since its typed incorrectly).

Answer (score 4):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F'[".]' 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} $2 in a{$0="//"$0} 1' list1 list2
//'include "test1.sv"
'include "test2.sv"
//'include "test3.sv"
'include "test4.sv"
```

How it works:

- `-F'[".]'`

  This tells awk to separate fields whenever a `"` or `.` occurs.
- `NR==FNR{a[$0]; next}`

  When reading the first file, `list`, this tells awk to create a key in associative array `a` equal the current line and then skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.

  More detail: `NR` is the total number of lines that awk has read so far.  `FNR` is the number of lines read so far from the current file.  This, when `FNR==NR`, we are reading the first file.
- `$2 in a{$0="//"$0}`

  When reading the second file, this tells awk to add `//` to the beginning of the line if the second field in the current line is a key in associative array `a`.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

#### Extended example

Using the additional line mentioned in the comments:

```
$ cat list1
test1
test3
usb30_suspend_resume
$ cat list2
'include "test1.sv"
'include "test2.sv"
'include "test3.sv"
'include "usb30_suspend_resume.sv"
'include "test4.sv"
$ awk -F'[".]' 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} $2 in a{$0="//"$0} 1' list1 list2
//'include "test1.sv"
'include "test2.sv"
//'include "test3.sv"
//'include "usb30_suspend_resume.sv"
'include "test4.sv"
```

#### Adapting for pastebin files

The files on pastebin have trailing blanks in list1 and both files have windows-style line-endings.  To handle this format, use:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $2 in a{$0="//"$0} 1' FS='[[:space:]]' list1.txt FS='[".]' list2.txt
```

Comment: Hmm. It seems to be skipping some names. For example, I have `include "usb30_suspend_resume.sv" and usb30_suspend_resume as the pattern, but it doesnt comment out the first instance. But some of the others do get commented.

Comment: @Javia1492 I updated files to include that line and, as you can see in the updated answer, it works for me.  It could get confused, though, if there was one or more extraneous leading or trailing whitespaces in `list1`.

Comment: Actually, this might be my mistake. It is not a 'include, but a `include. Does this change the command?

Comment: That will make no difference: `include and 'include are treated the same.  Could you upload somewhere for me to access the exact sample files that give you this problem?

Comment: List1: https://pastebin.com/yZvVQStx
List 2: https://pastebin.com/88j968n3

Comment: Eventually I want to do this with the following list: https://pastebin.com/vjrtXW1F so that if there is a match with the test names (the left hand side), the entire line is commented out.

Comment: So for another example i reran it and looked at some other test like pd3_rand_test_1 at towards the end of list1 (line 512) and compared did a diff of the new list2 to old list2 and its still uncommented. Maybe 20 tests total get commented out on my end.

Comment: @Javia1492 Thank you.  The pastebin files list1.txt and list2.txt explained a lot.  See updated answer for code to handle trailing whitespace and Windows-style line-endings.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I would do this interactively in Vim in less time than it would take to type any of the scripted solutions given so far.

```
vim list2
```

Then, read in list1 at the top.  (I'm assuming it will be easy to tell visually where it ends and where list2 starts, so no need to mark anything ahead of time—but you can `:1k a` first if you like so the original line 1 of list2 is marked.)

```
:0r list1
```

After this command your cursor will be at the start of the file, on the first word `test1`.

Press `*` to go to next instance of word under cursor.  (That will be the line you want to comment.)

Press `I` to enter insert mode (at the first non-whitespace character on the line, since you used a capital `I` and not lower case) and type `//` and then press Escape.

Press `n` to go to next instance of searched word.  (Since you're at the start of the line just after your `//` characters, your cursor will go to the instance you just found.  So press it again to go to the next instance.)

Assuming there was only the one instance to be commented, you'll now be at the start of the file again—the first line.  Press `j` to go down (or just press Enter to go to the first non-whitespace character of the next line—same result in this case).

Press `*` to go to the next `test3` instance, since that's what's under your cursor now.

**Press `.` to repeat the "commenting out line" action.**  The dot command is awesome.  :)

Press `n` again.  (Twice.)  In your example text, you're done now—you're back at the second line, `test3`.  If there were more lines to be commented, again just type `j*.nn`.  And if there is another, type `j*.nn` again.

When done (you're on `test3` or whatever the last line was from `list1`, just above the original first line from `list2`), press `dgg` to delete all lines from the current line to the first line of the file—so that the `list1` entries won't be there anymore.

In total, what you type is

```
vim list2<Enter>
```

to open the file, then:

```
:0r list1<Enter>
*I//<Esc>nn
j*.nn
j*.nn
j*.nn
(Repeat however many times)
dgg
```

Then to save and exit, type `:x` and press Enter.

---

EDIT:

I learned your "list1" is huge.  Doesn't matter; just use a macro.

After doing the above a few times so you are sure it works, type:

```
qkj*.nnq
```

This will record `j*.nn` as a macro in register `k`.

Run the macro by typing `@k`.

Run it again by typing `@@`.

Then run it 4000 times by typing `4000@@`.  But personally, I would do it in smaller chunks.  And perhaps not use the dot command in the macro but explicitly type `I//<Esc>`.

Point being, I would *still* do it interactively, and it would *still* take only a minute or two, regardless of how many lines I had to handle.  The magic of Vim.  :)

Comment: The file the OP pastebinned is almost 4000 lines.

Comment: @Nick, thanks, didn't realize that.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is:

```
 for each line of List2
     if line matches ANY pattern in List1 then
         print //line
     else
         print line
```

Here's an implementation in bash (or similar):

```
 while read line ;do
     if echo $line | fgrep -f List1 >/dev/null ;then
         echo "//$line"
     else
         echo "$line"
     fi
 done < List2
```